# Blender 2.80: Color changing in render result

Tags: rendering, color

I'm new to Blender

I want to make an simple animation so I deleted the light and using world light. However, after rendering all my images colors become very faint compared to render preview.

How can I fix the render result to looks like my render preview?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Could you post an screenshot of the situation? Which render engine are you using?

Comment: Don't forget to add the screenshots with the [built-in tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). Also, "did all the things needed" is really, **really** on the weak side of the description scale.

Comment: Try to add an Emission node to your material. here is an example of setup https://imgur.com/a/yRijNIa

Comment: I fixed my problem. Thank you guys a lot. Its because I was looking at LookDev mode and used Cycles engine instead of Eevee. 

@metaphor yeah.. I'll try to describe better and add screenshots if I have any problems in future. Thank you